# UDF to calculate CAGR from return data

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to make a UDF which will calculate the CAGR of a given range.

The data given to the function will typically be monthly return data, so i need to:

- Add 1 to each cell in range
- Multiply all cells together
- take the power of (1/(number in range/12))

If i do it manually i would type in the formula 
=product(rng+1)^(1/(Count(rng)/12))-1 and array enter CTRL+Shift+Enter

I have tried two different path to getting this done. The first is to basically do the before mentioned formula in vba.

```
Option Explicit

Function CAGR(rng As Range) As Double

Dim total As Double
Dim n As Integer
Dim pwr As Double

Total = Application.FormulaArray="=Product(rng+1)"
n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(rng)
pwr = (1 / (n / 12))

CAGR = Application.WorksheetFunction.Power(total,  pwr) - 1

End Function
```

However the line

```
Total=Application.formulaArray="=Product(rng+1)"
```

Won't Work presumebly because i'm using the formulaArray function wrong...

The other approach i have tried is to make the function with a loop, where i would like to add 1 to each cell value in the range and multiply them. (not the entire function).

```
Option Explicit

Function CAGR2(rng As Range) As Double

Dim cell As Variant
Dim k As Double
Dim n As Integer

For Each cell In rng
    cell.Value = cell.Value + 1
    Next cell

k = Application.WorksheetFunction.Product(rng)

CAGR2 = k

End Function
```

All the CAGR functions i have found on the internet seems to be on Price data, so i would like to stress that this function should calculate on return data (1%, -2%, 3% and so on).

I have been struggeling with this problem for hours so any help would be greatly appriciated!

Many thanks

Comment: `"=Product(rng+1)"` This won't give you what you expect. If you want to use a variable mid-string like that, you'll have to break it up like `"=Product(" & rng & "+1)"` Not to mention that `FormulaArray` is a method on the Range object, not Application...

Comment: I think it's because `total` is a `double`, but the way you've written it, it's a string. Can you even do ` X = Y = Z` in VB? You may need to spread that over two lines. But why are you using a formula array for `Total` instead of just doing `product * (rng + 1)`?  You need `evaluate`. Edit: Oh, I see what you were trying, `rng` is a variable in your formula.... others got it.

Comment: @BruceWayne You're right, you can't assign like that. It evaluates to "Set X to the boolean value of (Y is equal to Z)". Once I finally get around to finishing the VBA docs I'm working on we'll have a place to link for this sort of issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the evaluate function:

```
CAGR = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("Product(" & rng.address(1,1,xlA1,True) & "+ 1)^(1/(Count(" & rng.address(1,1,xlA1,True) & ")/12))-1")
```

Comment: Thank  you so much for your help! i added +1 to the end of the product function and it is working perfectly! Much appriciated.

Comment: @T.Jensen sorry missed that.  Please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only the one posing the question can do.

Answer (score 0):

I liked your loop idea and think you are on the right track. Building off of your second piece of code

```
Option Explicit

Function CAGR2(rng As Range) As Double

Dim cell As Variant
Dim n As Integer

CAGR2 = 1
n = 0
For Each cell In rng
    CAGR2 = CAGR2 * (cell.Value + 1)
    n = n + 1
Next cell

CAGR2 = CAGR2 ^ (1 / (n / 12))

End Function
```

Notice that I keep track of the number of cells in the range with `n` and we just accumulated the product of each cell with `CAGR2`. Once the product has fully accumulated, we then take it to the correct exponent. I'm not sure, but you may need to subtract one after it's all said and done.

Comment: `rngCount` isn't declared (or used).  The exponentiation should probably go inside the loop - doing it after multiplying all of the cell values loses precision on large arrays.

Comment: This worked perfectly, and saved me a lot of time! Thank you so much for taking your time to help me.

Comment: My pleasure. I'm helped plenty on this site as well. It's nice to be able to give back to the community when I can.